# My car has fungus on seats, any remedies?

Tags: interior, seat-cars

My car seat are made up of fabric and in monsoon, fungus builds up on it and a stench can be smelled when I open the car, please suggest remedies

Comment: You have leaks.  Find them. Fix them.

Comment: after you fix the leaks, throw the seats away and get some new ones. that smell will likely never come out.

Answer (score 1):

with craigslist or facebook market place you can find a good deal on seats in good condition well god luck. 
as for the seats that you have right now you may eliminate the odor for some time but problem will alway come back at you therefore I would suggest just finding a new set of seats (people junk cars all the time and in many cases cars are in great condition and you can get parts of from them)